# WhatsApp voice message not working after WebRTC call

Tags: ionic-framework, webrtc

We have developed a community app with WebRTC. Where admin calls (from web panel) to app. 
After every call on phone WhatsApp voice feature does not work. User have to close our app from phone memory in order for Whatsapp voice to work. 
I know its very strange issue but any help would be great.

Comment: iOS or Android ?

Comment: @Rubycon Android